# the other/other

Tags: word-choice, articles

I have been struggling with the understanding of the others/others.
I know that'the other or the other' is used when you talk about rest of some identified group, it is like 'the remaining ones'.

So e.g. here:

> I implemented 50 out of 100 requirements. The others will be
>   implemented tomorrow.

Is that correct?

Answer (score 8):

In this specific context, the difference between using the article or not is quite clear-cut...

> 1a: The others will be implemented tomorrow *- **all** the others*
>    1b: Others will be implemented tomorrow *- **some** (but usually **not all**) of the others*

---

The general principle is you include the definite article ***the*** when the thing(s) being referenced have already been mentioned before, or are clearly defined in some other way for the current context (you're talking about something *specific*, where both speaker and audience know exactly *which one(s)*.

Applying that principle in OP's example, the only possible way ***the*** others can unambiguously identify a specific group of "requirements" is if it's ***all*** the ones that haven't already been implemented.

---

Note that things change if the context provides more information. Consider...

> 2: I have high, medium, and low-priority requirements to implement. I did the high-priority ones today.
>    2a: The medium-priority requirements will be implemented tomorrow
>    2b: Medium-priority requirements will be implemented tomorrow

In that case, 2a and 2b would normally both be understood as meaning the same thing (***all*** medium-priority requirements), so you might say it's just a stylistic choice whether to include the article or not. But per @CowperKettle's comment below, it's at least *possible* to differentiate on the grounds that 2b is more appropriate if you mean ***some*** medium-priority requirements will be implemented tomorrow [but not all - there are a lot of these, and it will take several days to implement them all].

Also note that if we substitute ***rest*** (or other unambiguous terms such as ***remaining/outstanding*** requirements) instead of ***other***, the article *must* be included, as per the general principle above.

Comment: I'll add one comment for the sake of completeness: We can use the adjective _other_ when it precedes a plural noun. So, we could offer as alternative 1c: _The other requirements will be implemented tomorrow._ The same usage of _the_ applies; if we remove the word _the_, it means some (but probably not all) will be implemented: _Other requirements will be implemented tomorrow._

Comment: @J.R.: Yes - effectively, *others* is a "contracted form" of *other requirements*, but if we drop the primary noun we still need the pluralising ***s***, so it gets attached to *other*. Considering your comment in light of the final sentence of my answer, we also end up with the observation that if there's only ***one*** "other" (i.e. - the referent is unambiguous), then again the article *must* be included. *"I finished one of my two jobs today. **The** other will be done tomorrow."*

Comment: I don't understand why in your second example "Medium priority requirements" in 2b cannot mean "some, probably not all".

Comment: @CowperKettle: You're quite right. I've just revisited this page because I got an upvote (yours?) before noticing I was also being pinged by a comment. And my first thought in glancing at my text above was *I seem to have tailed off without explaining **why** "things change". It was a while ago, so I've completely forgotten how I came to post it as is - perhaps I got called away or something. Anyway, ty for the heads up - I'll edit.